# cannot access dispatch method in a util file: react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a util/usedecoder.ts file that looks like:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const decoder = ({latitude, longitude}: any) => {
  const url =
    'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' +
    latitude +
    '+' +
    longitude +
    '&key=########';

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function (response: any) {
      const timestamp = response.data.timestamp.created_http;
      const address = response.data.results.filter((data: any) => data.confidence > 8)[0].formatted;
      return {timestamp, address};
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      dispatch(addLocation(data)); <-------- Not working
    })
    .catch(function (error: string) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export function addLocation(data: any) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_LOCATION',
    data: data,
  };
}
```

My file does not know anything about the dispatch method. Why so? Am I configuring something wrong at the App level?

My index.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import App from './App';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore, applyMiddleware, compose} from 'redux';
import {rootReducer} from './redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  public render() {
    const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
```

My App.tsx looks like:

```
import {useGeolocation} from './utils/useGeolocation';
import {decoder} from './utils/useDecoder';
import Home from './screens/Home';
import * as React from 'react';
const App = () => {
  const geoLocation = useGeolocation();
  decoder(geoLocation[1]);
  return <Home />;
};

export default App;
```

How do I use the dispatch functionality in useDecoder?

Comment: `dispatch` is not a global function. You have to provide it into `decoder`. Use asynchronous redux action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've setup/configured your store with the redux-thunk middleware, and correctly connected the app/component to the store, then your action creator simply needs to return a top-level function that receives the `dispatch` prop.

[async-action-creators](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions#async-action-creators)

```
export const decoder = ({latitude, longitude}: any) => dispatch => { // <-- return a function with dispatch as parameter

  const url =
    'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' +
    latitude +
    '+' +
    longitude +
    '&key=########';

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function (response: any) {
      const timestamp = response.data.timestamp.created_http;
      const address = response.data.results.filter((data: any) => data.confidence > 8)[0].formatted;
      return {timestamp, address};
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      dispatch(addLocation(data)); // <-- can now dispatch
    })
    .catch(function (error: string) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thank you Sir :) That worked a charm. Alternatively I used a hook. useDispatch!

Comment: @Ackman I'm actually surprised that works as it doesn't appear that `decoder` is a react component nor uses the react hook naming convention, though you named the file `useDecoder`.

Comment: yeah, that hook has the capability to grab the reference from anywhere within the App component I guess.

Answer (score 0):

```
I solved it by using a hook:

import axios from 'axios';
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux'; ----> 

export const decoder = ({latitude, longitude}: any) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const url =
    'https://api.opencagedata.com/geocode/v1/json?q=' +
    latitude +
    '+' +
    longitude +
    '&key=30eb4ee11aeb43848e1db3a7056ad91f';

  axios
    .get(url)
    .then(function (response: any) {
      const timestamp = response.data.timestamp.created_http;
      const address = response.data.results.filter((data: any) => data.confidence > 8)[0].formatted;
      return {timestamp, address};
    })
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch(addLocation(data));
    })
    .catch(function (error: string) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export function addLocation(data: any) {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_LOCATION',
    data: data,
  };
}
```